# Why do we need a "MultiRepositoryProvider" and a separate "MultiBlocProvider"?

Tags: flutter, bloc

So I'm going to ask what might be a dumb question here - but why is there / do we need a "MultiRepositoryProvider", AND a "MultiBlocProvider" when using the Bloc library with Flutter ? Why not just have a MultiBlocProvider ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code for both `MultiRepositoryProvider` and `MultiBlocProvider` are practically the same:

[MultiRepositoryProvider](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/packages/flutter_bloc/lib/src/multi_repository_provider.dart)

```dart
class MultiRepositoryProvider extends MultiProvider {
  /// {@macro multi_repository_provider}
  MultiRepositoryProvider({
    Key? key,
    required List<RepositoryProviderSingleChildWidget> providers,
    required Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, providers: providers, child: child);
}
```

[MultiBlocProvider](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/packages/flutter_bloc/lib/src/multi_bloc_provider.dart)

```dart
class MultiBlocProvider extends MultiProvider {
  /// {@macro multi_bloc_provider}
  MultiBlocProvider({
    Key? key,
    required List<BlocProviderSingleChildWidget> providers,
    required Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, providers: providers, child: child);
}
```

So this is just a convenience to maintain clear code.

**The difference lies in `RepositoryProvider` and `BlocProvider`:**

`RepositoryProvider` does not handle updates. You cannot "change" the repository at runtime, while `BlocProvider` does - if you change the object at runtime, then widget, that uses it will rebuild.